# My PC does not ask password in Login even if I set it to ASK on login

Tags: login, password

When I first installed Ubuntu 11.04 I marked **NOT** to ask password in login. Then, ofcourse, it didn't ask me password on login. But now I want the OS to ask login password as I have many critical datas stored. 
I changed the settings to **Password: Asked in Login** but it doesn't work. My Ubuntu doesn't ask password in login.
What should I do now?

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem.
Try running this command:

```
sudo gpasswd -d $USER nopasswdlogin
```

this should work.

The thing is that my user was in the `nopasswdlogin` group. I had to install the `gnome-system-tools` which has the GUI to manage users and groups. Then I ran the `users-groups manager` and change my user to NOT be part of the `nopasswdlogin` group. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

> System Setting -> System -> Login Screen -> Unlock

You will need to enter your password.

Then select the option that says "Show the screen for choosing who will log in"

Comment: @Bibek Karki: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explains [How to disable password prompts in Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-disable-password-prompts-in-ubuntu.html). 
In case if you want to enable password prompts, try to do that vice versa