# Why Ubuntu doesn't ask me for password before login?

Tags: 11.10, password, keyrings, database, unlock

When I had 11.04, there was an option "ask for password", something like this. I checked it out, and instead of password field I got "login" button. Now, when I got 11.10, I doesn't see that option. But I still don't have "password" field. Instead of typing password and hiting enter, I have to click on "Login" button, and when I see my wallpaper etc. window asking for "password to unlock keyring database" appear :/.

How can I change that? I want to type my password, now everybody can login into my account without knowing password. And how to get rid of that window?

My question is similar to this: [My PC does not ask password in Login even if I set it to ASK on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60343/my-pc-does-not-ask-password-in-login-even-if-i-set-it-to-ask-on-login) but I can't see that option in 11.10 :/. Please, help, it's little bug, but it's annoying me :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to create second user with admistrator role? Check if it happens the same for the new one, what happens when you just log off from one of the accounts and try to change your settings from the new user.

Comment: Okay, I created new user with root priviledges. I logged into that new user, and changed my password. Now I got password field instead of Login button :). But I still got window appearing after login, asking for password to "Unlock the keyring database", how can I get rid of that window?

Comment: *that window asked me for password to "Unlock your login keyring", I made mistake in previous post.

Comment: Okay, thanks for help. I get rid of that window, using this advice http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/18/enter-password-to-unlock-your-keyring-prompt-in-ubuntu/ Now everything is good :-).

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you before. I'm glad you were able to fix everything ;)